# JSF Primefaces: How to keep page focus of selected row after editing? (Paginator, Filtering)

Tags: jsf, filter, primefaces, datatable, pagination

I'm using the datatable of Primefaces, where the User is able to select a row and edit it. The datatable contains about 10 pages, furthermore it includes a *paginator* and the *filter feature*.

So, if the user selects a row (e.g. from page 3) using the filtering and manipulate it, the datatable updates the value and goes back to page 1. But I need to display page 3, the page where the row is selected.

That's how my datatable looks like:

```
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row"
                widgetVar="dataTableWidget" style="overflow:hidden;"
                value="#{bean.tableData}"
                filterEvent="enter"
                filteredValue="#{bean.filteredTableData}"
                paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                rowKey="${row.id}"
                selection="#{bean.selectedRow}"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                editable="true">
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try to keep the datatable into the previous state before editing, just don't update it. However you should spicify your edition code, I suppose you're updating it after `rowEdit` event?

Comment: do you update whole datatable after user is done editing?

Comment: Yes, the entire table.